# CMS for searchable library/gallery of documents

Tags: pdf, cms, gallery

Similar to [this site](https://www.psychologytools.com/downloads/cbt-worksheets-and-therapy-resources/) (screenshot example below) we are looking for a CMS or library that would provide a searchable interface for a collection of documents (pdf, etc).  For example, documents would be organised by folder, or tags, and the interface would provide checkboxes and a search field to narrow the document search.  Perhaps a thumbnail of the document would be nice. Tags would be pulled from PDF keywords & subject.

Based on other questions I've read, I'm leaning towards Google Docs api, or perhaps Box.net.  Maybe Alfresco Community Edition.

Wondering if there are more current solutions (other posts I searched were a bit dated).  Lightweight is better.  We don't need a full CMS or blog.

For example:

[image: example interface]